# Bash: set a shell variable in the middle of the pipeline

Tags: bash

I have text coming from some command (in example it's `echo -e "10 ABC \n5 DEF \n87 GHI"`). This text goes through the pipeline and I get wanted output (in example it's `GHI`). Wanted output is sent to the following pipeline step (in example it's `| xargs -I {} grep -w {} FILES |`).
My question is:
I want to append a variable to an "inter pipe" output before it's sent to a following step - How can I do this?

---

Example:

```
echo -e "10 ABC \n5 DEF \n87 GHI" | 
   sort -nr -k1 |
   head -n1 |
   cut -f 2 |  # Wanted output comes here. I want to append it to a variable before it goes to `grep`
   xargs -I {} grep -w {} FILES |
   # FOLLOWING ANALYSIS
```

Comment: are you trying to store an intermediate result? or insert a variable's value into the stream?

Comment: Insert it to a stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this

```
echo -e "10 ABC \n5 DEF \n87 GHI" | sort -nr -k1 | head -n1 | cut -f 2 | while read MYVAR; do echo "intermediate value: $MYVAR"; echo $MYVAR | xargs -I {} grep -w {} FILES; done
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't set a shell variable in the middle of the pipeline, but you can send the output to a file using the `tee` command, and then read that file later.

```
echo -e "10 ABC \n5 DEF \n87 GHI" | 
   sort -nr -k1 |
   head -n1 |
   cut -f 2 |
   tee intermediate.txt |
   xargs -I {} grep -w {} FILES |
   # FOLLOWING ANALYSIS

# intermediate.txt now contains 87 GHI
```

Comment: And how can I `VARIABLE=$(cat intermediate.txt)` before `xargs -I {} grep -w {} FILES ` (or any other pipeline steps)?  What I want here is to put a command in the middle of the pipeline.

Comment: @Pgibas you can't. If you want to assign to a variable, you need to split the pipeline somewhere. Probably `VAR=$(echo ... cut); <<<$VAR xargs ...`

Answer (score 1):

*Insert it to a stream.* so I think your looking just to add the ?contents? of a variable to every 'line' from the stream?  This *prepends* the contents of $example

ie

```
   example="A String"
   echo -e "10 ABC \n5 DEF \n87 GHI" | 
   sort -nr -k1 |
   head -n1 |
   cut -f 2 |  
   sed s/^/$example/ |
   xargs -I {} grep -w {} FILES |
   # FOLLOWING ANALYSIS
```

sed s/$/$example/ to append

NB *I* tend to do lot of things this way in bash, but a long pipeline of cuts, seds and heads etc does suggest *maybe* its time to break out awk or perl.